# Scylla node going down due to storage I/O error

Tags: scylla

The scylla nodes suddenly go down (Down and Normal state).
Found this checking the logs

```
Feb 06 08:37:11 scylla-zeograph-prod-eu-3 scylla[13753]:  [shard 11] storage_service - Disk error: std::system_error (error system:61, No data available)
Feb 06 08:37:11 scylla-zeograph-prod-eu-3 scylla[13753]:  [shard 11] sstable - failed reading index for /var/lib/scylla/data/idgraph1/graphindex-48ff28e0322211ea92ea00000000000a/mc-1019-big-Data.db: storage_io_error (Storage I/O error: 61: No data available)
Feb 06 08:37:11 scylla-zeograph-prod-eu-3 scylla[13753]:  [shard 0] storage_service - Stop transport: starts
Feb 06 08:37:11 scylla-zeograph-prod-eu-3 scylla[13753]:  [shard 0] storage_proxy - Exception when communicating with 10.38.0.5: storage_io_error (Storage I/O error: 61: No data available)
Feb 06 08:37:11 scylla-zeograph-prod-eu-3 scylla[13753]:  [shard 0] storage_service - Thrift server stopped
Feb 06 08:37:11 scylla-zeograph-prod-eu-3 scylla[13753]:  [shard 0] storage_service - CQL server stopped
Feb 06 08:37:11 scylla-zeograph-prod-eu-3 scylla[13753]:  [shard 0] storage_service - Stop transport: shutdown rpc and cql server done
Feb 06 08:37:11 scylla-zeograph-prod-eu-3 scylla[13753]:  [shard 0] gossip - My status = NORMAL
Feb 06 08:37:11 scylla-zeograph-prod-eu-3 scylla[13753]:  [shard 0] gossip - Announcing shutdown
Feb 06 08:37:11 scylla-zeograph-prod-eu-3 scylla[13753]:  [shard 0] storage_service - Node 10.38.0.5 state jump to normal
Feb 06 08:37:11 scylla-zeograph-prod-eu-3 scylla[13753]:  [shard 11] sstable - failed reading index for /var/lib/scylla/data/idgraph1/graphindex-48ff28e0322211ea92ea00000000000a/mc-1019-big-Data.db: storage_io_error (Storage I/O error: 61: No data available)
```

What could the possible issue be ?

Comment: You have an I/O error, you should look in the system log and dmesg.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should know that when Scylla cannot read one of the database files (as happened in this case), it refuses to boot at all, as you noticed. While it would have been easy to just skip this error and continue to read more files, this is dangerous - the node can then be answering requests with only a subset of the data, or potentially, even corrupted data. Since data in Scylla is normally replicated on, often, 3 nodes, it is safer to have one node go down and the other two answer (until, eventually, the operator will bring up a third), than to have the node go up with incorrect data.

Getting this introduction out the way, I guess your next question is why you have this I/O error. The ENODATA you got isn't the run-of-the-mill I/O error...  As Avi suggested in a comment, please see if the system log also reports errors. What kind of filesystem do you have /var/lib/scylla/data/ in? If this problem persists, and you can reproduce this on a recent version of Scylla, you can also ask this question on the Scylla developer mailing list (scylladb-dev@googlegroups.com).